It's possible to implement PageView with GoRouter?
I can't find answer in the internet about this and I am wondering if it's possible to create a view with BottomNavBar and PageView.
Default PageView has required parameters children so I think it's not possible, but with constructor PageView.builder we can pass child using ShellRoute to itemBuilder of PageView.builder.
Is my thinking good or IT won't work that way?
Or maybe there is other solution to implement PageView functionalities using GoRouter?

smells like XY problem, what actually do you want to achieve?

you might be looking for shellRouter

@pskink Swiping between pages and that pages are routes from GoRouter

may I ask what for do you need gorouter here?

Nested navigation in this pages

and if you swipe to page 1 then back to 0 and again to page 1 then the navigation stack should be 0 > 1 > 0? i still cannot see the purpose of combining PageView and top page navigation

I mean something like StatefulShellBranch where pages have own sub-routes. I need PageView to just swipe between main routes

something like this: PageView(children: [Router.withConfig(...), Router.withConfig(...), Router.withConfig(...), ])? it has three independent routers, each one with own sub-pages

I guess, it will work that way?

Router.withConfig is a normal Widget, why wouldnt it work?

Here is an example pic
The StatefulNavigationShell allows for maintaining state and managing navigation within different branches of your application.
/// This will contains all the routes name of the application
class AppRoutes {
  /// THese are the routes name that will be used in the code
  static const first = 'first';
  static const second = 'second';
  static const third = 'third';

  /// THese are the routes path that will show in the url
  static const firstPath = '/first';
  static const secondPath = '/second';
  static const thirdPath = '/third';
}

class RouterConfiguration {
  static final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  static final router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: AppRoutes.firstPath,
    debugLogDiagnostics: false,
    navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,  
    routes: [
      StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
        builder: (c, state, navShell) {
          return DashboardScreen(navigationShell: navShell);
        },
        branches: [
          StatefulShellBranch(
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: AppRoutes.firstPath,
                name: AppRoutes.first,
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return const Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: Text('first screen'),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: AppRoutes.secondPath,
                name: AppRoutes.second,
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return const Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: Text('second screen'),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                name: AppRoutes.third,
                path: AppRoutes.thirdPath,
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return const Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: Text('Third screen'),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
}

Dashboard Screen:
StatefulNavigationShell used goBranch function for switching screen
class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;

  const DashboardScreen({super.key, required this.navigationShell});

  @override
  State<DashboardScreen> createState() => _DashboardScreenState();
}

class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: widget.navigationShell),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 80,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
            topRight: Radius.circular(25),
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
              blurRadius: 10,
              offset: Offset(0, -5),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 26),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              NavBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'First',
                onTap: () {
                  widget.navigationShell.goBranch(0);
                },
              ),
              NavBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                label: 'Second',
                onTap: () {
                  widget.navigationShell.goBranch(1);
                },
              ),
              NavBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                label: 'Third',
                onTap: () {
                  widget.navigationShell.goBranch(2);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NavBarItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget icon;
  final String label;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  const NavBarItem({
    super.key,
    required this.icon,
    required this.label,
    required this.onTap,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          icon,
          SizedBox(height: 4),
          Text(label),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

I think you are looking for this right? If you need any further details, let me know!
